# Some things I can't understand about Ohm's Law

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

**I** can't understand how PD is directly proportional to resistance and current intensity at the same time, although they are inverse, I know that an increasing in PE leads to an increase in current intensity and an increase in heat that leads to increase the resistance but aren't this means that resistance and intensity by this way are direct and how the equation is balanced when they all increase. **second** is resistance affect the current intensity or the the opposite only and in this state what will the be relation on the graph (resistance on **X**) (current on **Y**).
**Finally** how increasing in resistance leads to increase of potential difference (how this happen)
and how this increasing  doesn't increase the intensity

Comment: Note that Ohm's law is valid in circuits where resistance is independent of voltage and current - i.e, a constant. These are called _ohmic_ circuits. Circuits where resistance of conductors is changed by temperature are not ohmic - where Ohm's law does not always hold true.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I’m having a hard time parsing this question, and also you’re asking a few questions at once. It works better for the stack exchange format if you ask one clear question at a time. Please edit your question for clarity.